# Windows Server 2016 connection to IKEv2 PSK VPN

Tags: windows, server, vpn, ipsec

I need to configure a Windows Server 2016 to connect to a VPN, using IKEv2 with PSK but I do not find how to achieve this, it seems that Windows can handle IKEv2 using certificate, but in my case I can only connect using a PSK, and I can not find how to do this...
Does anyone know how to join this kind of VPN network?